# How to allow only jpg,jpeg,png image only in laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation

Controller

```
public function store_room_detail(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'room_image' => 'required|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|max:2048'
    ]);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

View:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.store-room-detail') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="room_image">Room Image</label>
            <input type="file" class="col-md-6" id="room_image" name="room_image[]"> 
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary add_more mb-3">
                Add More
            </a>
            <div class="wrap"></div>
            @if ($errors->has('room_image'))
                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('room_image') }}</span>
            @endif
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In the above code. Validation working fine but when I upload jpg, png image then it will again show that `The room image must be a file of type: png, jpg, jpeg`. I don't why? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: You have `room_image[]` in your form which makes it an array of images not a single image

Comment: @apokryfos but I am also have add more button where I am going to add multiple images that's why I am using `room_image[]`.

Answer (score 2):

you should validate like this because you send an array in request:

```php
$request->validate([
    'room_image' => 'required',
    'room_image.*' => 'required|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|max:2048'
]);
```